# Detect mobile browser name and version

Tags: javascript, mobile-browser

I'm trying to find a javascript code that detects mobile browser name and version but with no luck so far.

Any help will be greate...

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jilius, why do you want this?

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want ...

Comment: Hi, yes I need it for work. What I want is to detect iPhone's and Android's native browsers. Meaning the ones that came with the phone (for example Safari for iPhone/iPad). Don't even know what browser is used on Android phones..

Answer (score 1):

Check this : [Browser detect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Use the navigator object. That will help you

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script>

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>
```

Comment: The quality of the code made me think that it was from W3schools. And guess what - [I'm right](https://www.google.nl/search?q=txt+%3D+%22%3Cp%3EBrowser+CodeName%3A+%22+%2B+navigator.appCodeName+%2B+%22%3C%2Fp%3E%22%3Btxt%2B%3D+%22%3Cp%3EBrowser+Name%3A+%22+%2B+navigator.appName+%2B+%22%3C%2Fp%3E%22%3Btxt%2B%3D+%22%3Cp%3EBrowser+Version%3A+%22+%2B+navigator.appVersion+%2B+%22%3C%2Fp%3E%22%3Btxt%2B%3D+%22%3Cp%3ECookies+Enabled%3A+%22+%2B+navigator.cookieEnabled+%2B+%22%3C%2Fp%3E%22%3Btxt%2B)! Please don't copy-paste code without proper attribution: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: @RobW - yes but good exaple for detect is over here : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html link also given by me in answer ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that this code doesn't detect all new mobile browsers such as Chrome. Actually what I'm looking for is a code that detects native browsers, what I mean by that is Safari for iPhone and Android's native browser which I don't know what it is... and so on..